# Add Hook for clearing transient when post is added

Tags: query, cache, transient

I have fragment caching implemented in a page. I've got the codes from https://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited/.

Which goes like this:

```
    function fragment_cache($key, $ttl, $function) {
      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        call_user_func($function);
        return;
      }
      $key = apply_filters('fragment_cache_prefix','fragment_cache_').$key;
      $output = get_transient($key);
      if ( empty($output) ) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func($function);
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        set_transient($key, $output, $ttl);
      }
      echo $output;
    }
```

And I want to clear the transient set when a post is added.
How can i do that?

Comment: because i have this `taxonomy.php` that loads all the post under it. The looping was within the fragment cache. I just thought that if i add new post under that taxonomy, it won't show the new post because the time has not yet elapse. Is that how it works right? or i am mistaken? @N00b Help me

Comment: you need to implement `save_post` and `delete_post` hooks IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your active theme's functions.php file.

`function wpse_delete_query_transient( $post ) {
    // Deletes the transient when a new post is published
    delete_transient( 'd_results' );
}
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'wpse_delete_query_transient' );`

This will delete the transient every time when a new post is published.

If you want to delete the transients on differrent post status transitions, you may refer [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)